# discord python music bot (bad operand type for unary +: 'dict') error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, youtube-api

hi im having a problem with my discord music bot's "play" command

this the code :

```
@client.command()
async def play(ctx,url):
     FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options':'-reconnect 1 reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options':'-vm'}
     YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
     vc = ctx.voice_client

     with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
         info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
         url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
         source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,++FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
         vc.play(source)
```

and this is the error :

```
Command raised an exception: TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `**` to unpack dictionary, not `++`.

Check this:

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx,url):
     FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options':'-reconnect 1 reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options':'-vm'}
     YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
     vc = ctx.voice_client

     with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
         info = ydl.extract_info(url,download=False)
         url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
         source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
         vc.play(source)
```